# How to approach this sequence problem on analysis

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

A sequence of positive integers $a_n$ contains each positive integer exactly once. Assume that if $m\neq n$ then $$ \frac{1}{1998}<\frac{\vert a_m-a_n\vert}{\vert m-n\vert}<1998$$

Prove that $\vert a_n −n\vert < 2000000$ for all $n$

I tried but could't proceed further

Comment: further than what?